# How can use selfjoin with count in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, count

Query #1:

```
SELECT
    voter, COUNT(*) AS voter
FROM
    TxVotes
WHERE
    timestamp BETWEEN '2017-07-21 00:00:00.000' and '2017-07-22 00:00:00.000'
GROUP BY 
    voter
ORDER BY 
    COUNT(*) DESC
```

working..........

Query #2:

```
SELECT 
    author 
FROM
    Comments
WHERE
   AND language LIKE '%"ko"%'
```

working..............

I need query #3:

```
SELECT
    TxVotes.voter, TxVotes.count(*) AS TxVotes.voter
FROM
    TxVotes, Comments
WHERE
    TxVotes.voter = Comments.author
    AND timestamp TxVotes.BETWEEN '2017-07-21 00:00:00.000' AND '2017-07-22 00:00:00.000'
    AND Comments language LIKE '%"ko"%'
GROUP BY 
    TxVotes.voter
ORDER BY 
    TxVotes.count(*) DESC
```

But this is not working...

How can we use self join with count in SQL Server?

Comment: Help us help you - Can you share some sample data, the result you're getting for it and the result you're trying to get?

Comment: can you attach the error message?

Comment: Shouldn't it be TxVotes.timestamp and Comments.language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```
SELECT v.voter, COUNT(v.id) as numvoters
FROM TxVotes v JOIN
     Comments c
     ON t.voter = c.author 
WHERE v.timestamp >= '2017-07-21' AND
      v.timestamp < '2017-07-22' AND
      c.language LIKE '%"ko"%'
GROUP BY v.voter
ORDER BY COUNT(DISTINCT v.id);
```

I'm note sure if you want to count *voters* or some combination of votes and comments.  I'm guessing voters, hence `COUNT(DISTINCT)`.

Notes:

- *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.
- I doubt you want to include records from exactly midnight on 2017-07-22.  Hence, `>=` and `<` is better than `BETWEEN`.
- Table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.  In your case, they should also alleviate your confusion.  You qualify column names with table names.  You don't qualify functions.
- `COUNT(DISTINCT v.voter)` should count the number of votes.  This handles the case where there are multiple comments for a single voter.  Note:  Normally, I would handle this using `IN` or `EXISTS`, but I've followed your original logic.

Comment: If you're counting DISTINCT v.voter and grouping by v.voter, won't the count always be 1? Maybe count distinct TxVotes.PK_column?